# Dynamic query expression builder

Tags: c#, linq, expression

Hi i was wondering how can i achieve the query expression below in dynamic way :

```
DataTable _dataSourceMatrix = GetManager.Budget.GetAll().ConvertToDataTable();

switch (EntityType)
{
    case DomainType.Department:
        DataTable _departmentList = GetManager.DepartmentManager.GetAll().ConvertToDataTable();

        var _genericBudgetJoinDepartmentList = from a in _dataSourceMatrix.AsEnumerable()
                                               join b in _departmentList.AsEnumerable()
                                               on a.Field<int>("EntityID") equals b.Field<int>("DepartmentID")
                                               select new { EntityName = b.Field<string>("Name"), Period = a.Field<string>("Period"), Value = a.Field<double>("Value"), EntityID = a.Field<int>("EntityID") };

        _dataSourceMatrix = _genericBudgetJoinDepartmentList.OrderBy(x => x.Period).ConvertToDataTable();

        break;
}
```

As you can see i have a dynamic type of EntityType to indicate what sort of target datasource that needs to join with the _dataSourceMatrix. I dont want the code getting bloated by keep rewriting the same query expression with just the change of the target source to join. I had came across with some stuff like QueryBuilder, but it does not seems like able to achieve something that i wanted to be. Any idea for that ?

Comment: If you make this generic, how will you know which field to join on? If they do all have the same join fields, you may wish to reconsider your database design to normalize it

Comment: The join field has to be generic as well, hence the field comes in string. Different table different join field.

Comment: If you have to pass in the table name and all the join columns anyway... what do you get from making the method generic... Why not just create views with your joins and dump them straight to datatables if you want to cut down on code. I would reconsider this design as it seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to select the table and field based on the `EntityType`, there are a number of ways to set them, including using the `switch` `case` or creating a `Dictionary` indexed by `EntityType`. Once you have them selected, you can process the join:

```
DataTable _dataSourceMatrix = GetManager.Budget.GetAll().ConvertToDataTable();

DataTable _joinTable = null;
string _joinField = String.Empty;

switch (EntityType) {
    case DomainType.Department:
        joinTable = GetManager.DepartmentManager.GetAll().ConvertToDataTable();
        _joinField = "DepartmentID";
        break;
}


var _genericBudgetJoinDepartmentList = from a in _dataSourceMatrix.AsEnumerable()
                                       join b in _joinTable.AsEnumerable()
                                       on a.Field<int>("EntityID") equals b.Field<int>(_joinField)
                                       select new { EntityName = b.Field<string>("Name"), Period = a.Field<string>("Period"), Value = a.Field<double>("Value"), EntityID = a.Field<int>("EntityID") };

_dataSourceMatrix = _genericBudgetJoinDepartmentList.OrderBy(x => x.Period).ConvertToDataTable();
```